# Replace middle of string given a range

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

**Previous Question:**

How replace an interval char in string:

For example Apple to A***e

**Update:**

Need get char positions 0-4 and -4 (Reverse)

```
var transaction = '1234567890987651907';
console.log('1234****1907');
```

**Solution**

```
var str = "01340946380001281972";
str.replace(/^(\d{0,4})(\d{4})(.*)/gi,"$1 **** $2");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what is interval character?

Comment: 0-4 to -4 char
Example:
1234567890 to 1234**7890

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting comments with examples. Your example is not clear at all. You want to give a range and change that range to *?

Comment: I dont speak english very well, sorry... but i did updated.

Comment: So Apple to Apple is interval 1,-1 and the second is interval 4 to -4?

Comment: Yes, sorry just needing regex, i'll edited after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant this

```js
function maskIt(str, keep) {
  var len = str.length,
    re = new RegExp("(.{" + keep + "})(.{" + (len - keep * 2) + "})(.{" + keep + "})", "g")
  console.log(re)
  return str.replace(re, function(match, a, b, c) {
    return a + ("" + b).replace(/./g, "*") + c
  });
}
console.log(
  maskIt("1234567890", 4),
  maskIt("Apple", 1)
)
```

As a prototype:

```js
String.prototype.maskIt = function(keep) { // don't use arrow or lose "this"
  const re = new RegExp("(.{" + keep + "})(.{" + (this.length - keep * 2) + "})(.{" + keep + "})", "g");
  return this.replace(re, (match, a, b, c) => a + ("" + b).replace(/./g, "*") + c);
}
console.log(
  "1234567890".maskIt(4),
  "Apple".maskIt(1)
)
```

Using slice

```js
const maskIt = (str,keep) => {
  return str.slice(0,keep)+Array.from({length: str.length-keep-1},() => '*').join('')+ str.slice(-keep)
}
console.log(
  maskIt("1234567890",4),
  maskIt("Apple",1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the base strings functions:

```js
var input = "Apple";
var input_masked = input.substring(0, 1) + Array(input.length - 1).join("*") +
    input.substring(input.length-1);
console.log(input_masked);
```

This approach is to sandwich the middle characters, masked as `*`, between the first and last character of the input.

Comment: You can simplify more?

Comment: LOL...I don't know, can I simplify more?

Comment: I try that:

var str = "Mandarina";
str.replace(/^(\w{0,4})(\w{0,4})/g,"$1 **** $2");

Comment: Are you just wasting everyone's time?

Comment: I dont speak english very well, sorry... but i did updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the middle characters:

```js
const str = "Apple";
const output = `${str[0]}${"*".repeat(str.length - 2)}${[...str].pop()}`;
console.log(output);
```

Comment: He wants to tell the function how many to keep at start and how many at end, possibly symmetrically

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "01340946380001281972";
str.replace(/^(\d{0,4})(\d{4})(.*)/gi,"$1 **** $2");
```